# EF Core Insert operation - how does the SQL command work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

How does the following SQL command works?

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([Id] int, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [OrderLine] USING (
VALUES (@p1, @p2, 0),
(@p3, @p4, 1),
(@p5, @p6, 2),
(@p7, @p8, 3)) AS i ([Item], [OrderId], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Item], [OrderId])
VALUES (i.[Item], i.[OrderId])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[Id], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [t].[Id] FROM [OrderLine] t
INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[Id] = [i].[Id])
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];

',N'@p1 nvarchar(64),@p2 int,@p3 nvarchar(64),@p4 int,@p5 nvarchar(64),@p6 int,@p7 nvarchar(64),@p8 int',@p1=N'Item-1',@p2=1,@p3=N'Item-2',@p4=1,@p5=N'Item-3',@p6=1,@p7=N'Item-4',@p8=1
```

(It was generated by EF Core and it inserts some `OrderLine` entities).

**Edit:**
I understand the declaring of the TABLE type variable and have basic idea of MERGE operation. But having a hard time understanding how and when actually data gets inserted in the OrderLine table.

Comment: Do you understand any of it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever only Brent Ozar understood this when it was first discovdered

Comment: Is there a specific part of the query you don't understand? This isn't an `INSERT` either, it's a `MERGE` (though it is only inserting data, not updating).

Comment: @Larnu that query took Brent Ozar an entire article and a full 10K-row benchmark to explain. And even that article doesn't explain the `_Position`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know what it's doing, and understand it (and use the logic myself from time to time), my question was to the OP, but was also stating that (technically) the above it not an `INSERT`, but a `MERGE` (but just doing the `INSERT` only part of it). But I was asking the OP what parts they specifically don't understand. Getting a good understanding of what they do and don't makes explaining easier; especially if we can determine that they have base knowledge of the language.

Comment: @Larnu frankly, I think I should never have read that article because I may be tempted to use this at some point

Comment: Unfortunately, unless `OUTPUT` in an `INSERT` statement allows for columns outside of `inserted` to be referenced, I think we're stuck with it, @PanagiotisKanavos .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how and when actually data gets inserted in the OrderLine table.

The operative bit is `ON 1=0`

Which means rows are never matched, and so every row goes to

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([Item], [OrderId])
VALUES (i.[Item], i.[OrderId])
```

Comment: There's a lot more to it than that. Why not `INSERT OUTPUT VALUES` ?

Comment: INSERT ... OUTPUT can't output a column that wasn't inserted.  MERGE doesn't have that limitation, so the _Position column couldn't be returned to the client.  And that's what EF uses to correlate the returned data with the existing entities.

Answer (score 5):

That's an interesting question that deserves an entire article to answer. Fortunately, Brent Ozar wrote [The Case of Entity Framework Core’s Odd SQL](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/05/case-entity-framework-cores-odd-sql/).

That MERGE statement does essentially what an `INSERT ... OUTPUT inserted.ID VALUES (),(),()` would do. The clause `ON 1=0` ensures only the INSERT branch will execute. So why such convoluted syntax?

The reason for this odd SQL is performance for batched inserts. Specifically, 248% better performance in 10K rows.

There are only a few ways of inserting multiple rows in a table :

- You can write 5000 INSERT queries in a long batch, but that's *slow*. Almost 5000 times slower than a single big INSERT, as each statement has to modify indexes etc.
- You can pass a table-type parameter. But this is slow too, because the server has no way of knowing how many items are in that parameter and assumes just a single row. This can lead to very bad execution plans.
- Store in a table variable? Same problem as the table parameter
- You could write all those rows to a temp table first, then insert them in a target, but that has its own problems - what should the table be named? Is it unique?

**What about the IDs?**

The table variable is used to collect the generated ids, `_Position` is used to maintain the order even in case of parallel execution. And I suspect, that's why `INSERT VALUES` isn't used too.

Since EF Core just sent 5000 items in a single batch, it needs a way to retrieve 5000 new IDs in a way that allows it to identity which objects the IDs belong to. Typically, one would use an ID to identify rows, but there are no IDs to begin with!

The only thing that's left is to return the IDs in the same order the objects were inserted. `INSERT OUTPUT VALUES` does *not* guarantee that - without an ORDER clause, the server is free to return data in the cheapest way possible.

The only safe way to preserve IDs and order in this case is to store them with an explicit `_Position` value in `@inserted0` and return them in that order.

**Conclusion**

It's about performance, and as Brent Ozar says:

> So yes, the SQL isn’t perfect, but it’s 248% faster.
>
> **Brent says:** hoo, boy. This is…not ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer and the link. It helped. The next question would come to my mind definitely be the _why_ part. I can see that now.